# What should I change in SailsJS router.js to load routes from React-Router file?

Tags: reactjs, sails.js, webpack, react-router, babeljs

What should I change in my `config/routes.js` file to make it use `modules/router` files written for the React front-end ?

config/routes.js file:

`module.exports: {}`

module/router.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'
import App from './App'
import About from './About'
import Repos from './Repos'
import Repo from './Repo'
import Home from './Home'

module.exports = (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/repos" component={Repos}>
      <Route path="/repos/:userName/:repoName" component={Repo}/>
    </Route>
    <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
  </Route>
)
```

I am using webpack, babel for bundling. Really stuck with this.
Currently, the first page is rendered by `assets/index.html` but if I refresh from any other page (whose address is not `/`), I get 404 from the server, even though the path is defined in the react router file.
Please help.

**EDIT**
Here's my `index.js` file (serves as the React entry point):

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import routes from './routes'

render(
  <Router routes={routes} history={browserHistory}/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of your Router config? With the actual `<Router />` block that uses some kind of history like has or browser?

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Create a JSON bridge, and in routes.js of sails, load that routes.

Comment: @AliTorabi How should I create a JSON bridge ? I'm stuck there..

Comment: @myusuf Have you found this?

Comment: @Emo No, my team switched to VueJS.